# Приведение строки к Decimal в VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Имеется строка `7780.444`, как ее правильно привести к типу `Decimal` ?

Пробовал `CDec` и `Decimal.Parse` а так же пробовал `NFI`.

> P.S. Помогите разобраться в сути проблемы.

Comment: Пробовали - хорошо, но что не получилось то? Обычно проблемы с точка-запятая, решаются в C# указанием инвариантной локали для точки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Decimal.Parse("7780.444", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```